# MySQL database backup creates an empty file

Tags: java, backup, mysql

Her is the code I use to back up my database. I succesfully get a "backup.sql" file when I run this but when I check it,it's empty. There's no data so meaning I got no backup but an empty sql file instead.

Furthurmore, when I run this program, the system hangs and I have to end the process through task manager.

```
public void Backupdbtosql() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String executeCmd = "";
    executeCmd ="mysqldump -u root -p root mydb--add-drop-database -r D:\\database\\backup.sql";
    Process runtimeProcess =Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd);
    int processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();
    if(processComplete == 0){
        System.out.println("Backup taken successfully");
    } else {
        out.println("Could not take mysql backup");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is hanging waiting for you to enter a password, from the mysqldump documentation (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_password)

" If you use the short option form (-p), you cannot have a space between the option and the password."

Try:

```
executeCmd ="mysqldump -u root -proot mydb--add-drop-database -r D:\\database\\backup.sql";
```